# Create new variable from combined variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have created a python script which uses tensorflow with deep sort to detect and track vehicles in a video.
Depending on each vehicles position it gets a value to its attributes
Each vehicle has the following:
`Car.Id Car.Origin Car.Destination`

Origin and Destination can be any of E, N, S or V (but not the same).

So each vehicle should then have an ID, Origin and Destination as in

```
 Car.Id = 575
 Car.Origin = E
 Car.Destination = V
```

Now I append these to a Pandas dataframe and I can export unique combinations as in

```
 sum((df['orig']=='E') & (df['dest']=='V'))
```

However, this would mean I need to update 12 different variables in each loop (EE, EV, ES, NV, NS etc etc.)

So, I tried to dynamically create and set values through the loop as in the following code

```
exec(str(track.origin + track.destination) + "=" + str(sum((df['orig']==track.origin) & (df['dest']==track.destination))))
```

But still `Print(EV)` doesn't work.
So, I am stuck.
Should i put E, V, N, S in some dictionary and loop around it, or do you guys have any other tip or recommendation?
I really want these simple variables as EV and SV for different reasons.

Comment: `for k, d in df.groupby(['orig', 'dest']): print(d)`

Comment: Thank you, however it only seems to produce multiple dataframes